# Regex: replace some pieces of php code in sublime text

Tags: php, regex, search, replace, sublimetext3

I'm quite a beginner in regex and i'd like to replace some pieces of code in Sublime Text 3 editor using search and replace with regex.
Here is an example i'm trying to replace:

Piece of php code to find:

```
self::$_config::$_params['myKey1']['myKey2']['myKey3']['myKeyn']
```

and replace it with:

```
self::$_config::getParam('myKey1.myKey2.myKey3.myKeyn')
```

One or more keys can be defined in array.

My "search" regex is:

```
self::\$_config::\$_params\['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:(('\]\[')([a-zA-Z0-9]+))*)'\]
```

I'm looking for a "replace" solution to retrieve all the keys to format the code as expected (getParam() method instead of $_params property) with repeated capturing group $2: i'm not sure it is possible like this or the most adapted way to succeed. 
Obviously, i have a warning for $2: "A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration".

```
$2 is optional (unique key).

Each match in $3 ('\]\[') has to be replaced with a dot.
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: I have to replace these pieces of code in many files in my editor with a search and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of processes can't be done in one single step. All you have to do is going through at least two find / replace functions.

- Look for all consecutive `'\]\['` occurrences after a `self::$_config::$_params` and replace it with a `.`
- Then look for `\['` and `\']`, after `$_params` and end of statement respectively to replace them with `getParam('` and `')`

But there would be another workaround to do this...

### One-liner RegEx Solution

1. Put following string at the very end of file:

   ```
   getParam('.')
   ```

*You can do top step manually or through a find `\z` and replace with `getParam('.')` method through all files you need (this then wouldn't make it one-liner!)*

2. Do an <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to enable Regular Expression search while being on Find / Replace pane.
3. Copy / Paste below regex into search field:

   ```
   ((self::\$_config::)\$_params\['(?=[\s\S]*(getParam\('))|\G(?!\A))(\w+)(?|'\](?!\s*\[)(?=[\s\S]*('\)))|'\]\['(?=[^.]*+(\.)))
   ```
4. Copy / paste below replacement string into replacement field:

   ```
   \2\3\4\5
   ```
5. Click Replace All.
6. Remove `getParam('.')` from end of file.

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/vWyd1y/2/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, really impressed! I have to understand all your regex with several advanced notions in your demo. Thank you for the ST3 steps.